# Zend Form not showing after defining Element_File

Tags: forms, zend-framework

Below is my Zend_Form file (sorry for the terrible spacing)!!

```
<?
class Form_Participant extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $role = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('role');
    $role->setRequired(true)
               ->setLabel('Role at Competition*')
               ->setMultiOptions(array('Competitor','Coach'),array(0,1))
               ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($role);

    $salutation = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('salutation');
    $salutation->setRequired(true)
               ->setLabel('Salutation/Title')
               ->setMultiOptions(array('Mr.','Mrs.','Miss.','Ms.','Dr.','Other'),array(0,1,2,3,4,5))
               ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($salutation);     

    $first_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name');
    $first_name->setRequired(true)
               ->setLabel('First Name')
               ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($first_name);

    $last_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('last_name');
    $last_name->setRequired(true)
              ->setLabel('Last Name')
              ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($last_name);

    $preferred_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('preferred_name');
    $preferred_name->setRequired(false)
                   ->setLabel('Preferred Name (optional)')
                   ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($preferred_name);

    $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('gender');
    $gender->setRequired(true)
           ->setLabel('Gender')
           ->addMultiOptions(array('Female','Male'),array('0','1'))
           ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($gender);


    $email_address = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email_address->setRequired(true)
                  ->setLabel('Email Address')
                  ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($email_address);

    $year = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('year');
    $year->setRequired(true)
               ->setLabel('Year of Study')
               ->setMultiOptions(array('1st Year','2nd Year','3rd Year','4th Year','5th Year','Other'),array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
               ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($year);

    $major = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('major');
    $major->setRequired(true)
          ->setLabel('Major/Specialization')
          ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($major);

    $resume = new Zend_Form_Element_File('resume');
    $resume->setRequired(false)
           ->setLabel('Upload Resume (PDF format)')
           ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/schools/2013/resume')
           ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($resume);


    $food_preference = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('food_preference');
    $food_preference->setRequired(false)
                    ->setLabel('Dietary Restrictions/Allergies (optional)')
                    ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($food_preference);

    $disabilities = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('disabilities');
    $disabilities->setRequired(false)
                    ->setLabel('Do you have any disabilities? (optional)')
                    ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($disabilities);

    $emergency_contact = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('emergency_contact');
    $emergency_contact->setRequired(true)
                    ->setLabel('Emergency Contact')
                    ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($emergency_contact);

    $additional_info = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('additional_info');
    $additional_info->setRequired(false)
                    ->setLabel('Additional Information (optional)')
                    ->setDecorators($this->container());
    $this->addElement($additional_info);

    $this->addElement('submit', 'register_participant_submit', array('label' => 'Add Participant','class'=>'blue_button add_participant'));
}

private function container()
{
    return array(
                    'ViewHelper',
                    'Errors',
                    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
                    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'id'  => array('callback' => array(get_class($this), 'resolveElementId')))),
                    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
                    array(array('elementContainer' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-container')),
                );
}

 }
```

There is an Element_File in there too. Without it, everything works fine. With it, the form does not show up at all!!

This is how I call the form in my Controller:

```
 $Form_Participant = new Form_Participant();
 $Form_Participant->setMethod('post')
                  ->setAttrib('id','registration_form')
                  ->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does it produce any output when it is not display the form?  Does the error log contain anything?

Comment: No absolutely nothing. I just get a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

The File element must include the 'File' decorator or it will not render. If you check your error log you'll probably see an exception in there. You'll need to handle the decorators for the file element a little differently to how you are handling the others, something like this:

```
private function fileContainer()
{
    return array(
        'File',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'id'  => array('callback' => array(get_class($this), 'resolveElementId')))),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
        array(array('elementContainer' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-container')),
    );
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I removed the decorator for that File element, and it worked. So it is the decorator. But the decorator that you provided does not work! I basically need the label and the element to be inside one div (for every single one of them). Could you help me out?! Thanks!!!

Comment: The decorators I have in mine are exactly the same as yours except with the ViewHelper decorator switched for the File one. What markup is generated and how does it differ from your other elements?

Comment: But when I use your decorator, still nothing happens! I don't get anything! The page is completely blank

Comment: Check the error log to see what the error is. And you might want to turn on display_errors in development mode.